# How to create new dictionary with reversed keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Lets say I have a dictionary with many elements with the following format(just refer 3 here),

dict1 = {(1, 2): 10, (0, 1): 42, (11, 10): 5}

I want now

dict2 = {(1, 2): 10, (0, 1): 42, (11, 10): 5, (2, 1): 10, (1, 0): 42, (10, 11): 5}

Any proposals, please?

Comment: "Any proposals" isn't a viable stand in for showing us your attempts at solving the problem.  Simply posting an input and a desired output is usually frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new dictionary with reversed keys, then update it with the old dictionary:

```
>>> dict1 = {(1, 2): 10, (0, 1): 42, (11, 10): 5}
>>> dict2 = {k[::-1]:v for k,v in dict1.items()}
>>> dict2.update(dict1)
>>> dict2
{(1, 2): 10, (0, 1): 42, (11, 10): 5, (10, 11): 5, (1, 0): 42, (2, 1): 10}
```

Comment: What about `dict2 = {k[::-1]:v for k,v in dict1.items()}` and then `dict2.update(dict1)`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, Delgan thank you both, it is what i need!

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer, so that SO can properly archive the question.